# Inline CSS transitions/animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions, inline-styles

I have a project where users can enter custom css that becomes an inline style on a div. I tried putting in a `transition: all 2s linear` and a `transform: rotate(180deg)`, but there was no animation, it just started rotated 180deg.

Is there a way to do any sort of css animation but only with inline styles on the element?

Comment: I think you need some kind of trigger to start the animation

Comment: The animation won't work if there is no starting value.

Comment: You cannot add an animation inline since it requires a @keyframes rule in the css which cannot be applied to an element.